# Overriding and extending bean if application run on given profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

So let's say I've main bean annotated with @Service which is injected in another services with @Autowired.

```
@Service
@Order(100)
class MainService() {
   fun helloWorld() = "Hello"
}
```

And I would like to extend this service when running with another profile fg. ("custom"). So I have service as below:

```
@Service("mainService")
@Order(1)
class CustomService: MainService() {
    override fun helloWorld() = "Hello custom"
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'mainService' for bean class [MainService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [CustomService]

Have you any idea how could I extend and override bean under the same name? Its because I need to autowire it somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can use configuration beans to do this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class MainServiceDev {

    @Bean
    public MainService mainService() {
        return new MainService();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Profile("custom")
public class MainServiceCustom {

    @Bean
    public CustomService customService() {
        return new CustomService();
    }

}
```